# Activity with ListView don't handle back key event

Tags: android, listview, back, activitygroup, android-cursoradapter

I use ActivityGroup to realize the tab interface. In one tab, I have a Activity A with a ListView, when I click sur un item, another page opens (Activity B) in the tab, then when I want to go back to the first page(Activity A), sometimes it close l'application. I don't understand why..

I use MyCursorAdapter (sub class of SimpleCursorAdapter) for the ListView in the Activity A.

The problem don't appear every time I hit the back key. Just sometimes, occasionally. Especially when I wait for a moment (2mins for ex) before returning to the first page.

By debugging, I see when il don't go back to the first page, the "onBackPress" ou "onKeyDown" is not called.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with listactivities and I ended up overriding onBackPressed() in the listactivity to call the back function of the activitygroup it was a part of. not the best solution but it works for the most part.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && Groupname.group != null) {
       Groupname.group.popView();
       return true;
   }
   return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
```

you should add this code for the activity group page

and the class should be like this

```
public class Groupname extends ActivityGroup {

 public static Groupname group;
// any aditional code
}
```